# undefined method 'current_sign_in_ip' for User (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber

Interested in learning about BDD, I am following free Rails Testing Handbook mentioned in [Setting up a BDD stack on a rails 5 application](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-a-bdd-stack-on-a-rails-5-application), and have almost completed chapter 5 **Bootstrapping a User Authentication System**.

Last line of Page 39 of the book reads

> Everything should be green at this point

However when I run `bundle exec cucumber` I have two failing scenarios (User Logs in, and User logs out). Excerpt from the cucumber output is appended below:

```
 When I fill in the login form #  
 features/step_definitions/authentication_steps.rb:29  
 undefined method `current_sign_in_ip' for #<User:0x0055a41ac1eeb8> (NoMethodError)

./features/step_definitions/authentication_steps.rb:32:in `"I fill in the login form"'
          features/authentication.feature:15:in `When I fill in the login form'
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
                 :confirmable
end
```

db/migrate/20181221105428_add_trackable_to_devise.rb

```
class AddTrackableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
        add_column :users, :sign_in_count, :integer, default:0, null: false
        add_column :users, :current_sign_in_at, :datetime
        add_column :users, :last_sign_in_at, :datetime
        add_column :users, :current_sign_in_ip, :inet
        add_column :users, :last_sign_in_ip, :inet
  end
end
```

Complete code, and the pdf book are available on [github repo](https://github.com/beyond2013/bdd).

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you run `rake db:test:prepare` to run migrations in test env?

Comment: No I hadn't, thanks for the help, it solved this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run rake db:test:prepare to execute last migration in test env